# Does ProfileOptimization actually work?

Tags: multicore, jit, .net-4.5

One of the new performance enhanchements for .NET 4.5 is the introduction of the 'MultiCode JIT'.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882452.aspx) for more details.

I have tried this, but it seems to have no effect on my application.

The reason why I am interested is that my app (IronScheme) takes a good long time to startup if not NGEN'd, which implies a fair amount of JIT'ng is involved at startup. (1.4 sec vs 0.1 sec when NGEN'd).

I have followed the instructions on how to enable this, and I can see a 'small' (4-12KB) is created. But on subsequent startup, it seems to have absolutely no effect on improving the startup time. It is still 1.4 sec.

Has anyone actually seen (or made) this work in practice?

Also, are there any limitations on which code will be 'tracked'? Eg: assembly loading contexts, transient assemblies, etc. I ask this as the created file never seems to grow, but I am in fact generating a fair amount of code (in a transient assembly).

One bug that I did encounter was that `SetProfileRoot` does not seem to understand a / as a path separator, make sure to use \ .

Comment: I have been running this for some time, but I have no clue if it actually works...

Comment: FWIW, when I enable it for my main application (a commandline app), startup time goes from 1.8s to 1.2s, a 33% perf improvement. And I can repro this again by disabling it, so it certainly does some optimizations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The rule of thumb we use at Microsoft is that Multicore JIT gets you about half way towards NGEN startup performance. Thus if your app starts in 0.1 seconds with NGEN and 1.4 seconds without NGEN, we would expect Multicore JIT startup to take about 0.75 seconds.

That being said, we had to put some limitations in place to guarantee that program execution order is the same with and without MCJ. MCJ will sometimes pause the background thread waiting for modules to be loaded by the foreground thread, and will abort background compilation if there is an assembly resolve or module resolve event.

If you want to find out what's happening in your case, we have ETW (Event Tracing For Windows) instrumentation of the MCJ feature and we will be releasing a version of PerfView soon which will be able to collect these events by if you take a trace of your app startup.

**Update:** PerfView has been updated to be able to show background JIT information. Here are the steps to diagnosing with the latest version (1.2.2.0):

1. Collect a trace using PerfView of your application startup, either using Collect->Run or Collect->Collect from the main PerfView menu.
2. Assuming you used Collect-> Run, put the name of your .exe in the Command text box, pick a filename (i.e. IronScheme.etl), select Background JIT from Advanced Options, and click Run Command.
3. Close your application and double click on the IronScheme.etl file that gets generated.
4. Double click on the JIT Stats view in the list underneath IronScheme.etl, you should see something like this in the view that pops up:

> ```
> This process uses Background JIT compilation (System.Runtime.ProfileOptimize) 
>     Methods Background JITTed : 2,951 
>     Percent # Methods Background JITTed : 52.9% 
>     MSec Background JITTing : 3,901 
>     Percent Time JITTing is Background : 50.9% 
>     Background JIT Thread : 11308
> ```

You can click on "View Raw Background Jit Diagnostics" to see all of the MCJ events in excel. One question I forgot to ask: are you running this on a multicore machine or multicore VM? It is a common mistake to test out MCJ in a VM that only has a single logical processor.

Comment: Thanks :) I will let you know of the results.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see `Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimePrivate/ClrMulticoreJit/Common`. There is nothing with the 'private' suffix. Tried both 32/64.

Comment: It turns out I wasn't using the current publicly available version of PerfView. We will update it in a week or two to be able to diagnose the ETW events and I will provide instructions when we do so.

Comment: Hehe, sneaky, you edit the question 1 second before I post my reply ;p

Comment: Would it help if I provide you with a build till then? (only 1.4mb zipped). Only concern is startup speed.

Comment: Here is a build with the functionality enabled: http://build.ironscheme.net/IronScheme-95434.zip Run the 'v4' executables for .NET 4.5 32/(64/AnyCPU)-bit.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be sneaky, just didn't want to have bad instructions on the web :) Thanks for sharing your app, I will take a look at it and get back to you. I will also update this post with instructions once we have published a version of PerfView which can analyze the MCJ events.

Comment: Thanks, I meant it as a joke, like you had ESP ;p Looking forward to it.

Comment: I ran the IronScheme.Console-v4.exe and didn't see any profiles generated. Do I have the right version, where should I look for the profile?

Comment: The profile data is stored in 'AppData\Local\IronScheme\JITCache'. The version is correct.

Comment: Found the profile, thanks. Multicore JIT appears to be working for this app on my machine, with 1.1 sec of JIT time occurring on the background thread. CPU activity in the process lasts for 3.9 sec without MCJ to 2.8 sec with MCJ, and stopwatching the app from launch to console prompt goes from 3.2s to 2.4s. If you're not seeing the same, hold tight for a version of perfview which can tell you what's happening on your machine.

Comment: @DanTaylor are you on twitter?

Comment: @DanTaylor: Thanks, never got notified of your reply. I see the same times on every successive run.

Comment: @DanTaylor: I just tried it again. Nothing gets moved to the background JIT. This on a MBP (corei5 I believe, no vm). Same result in both 32/64 bit modes. It does gives some interesting info which I will dissect tonite (specifically related to JIT performance when dealing with huge methods, IL size = 192717, 32bit time = 176.9, 64bit time = 1261.7).

Comment: @DanTaylor: Somewhere between an IL size of 11k and 25k, performance of the JIT on 64bit deteriorates badly. Will run more tests on a better PC tonite from home.

Comment: @DanTaylor: Interestingly, MC JIT works on home PC, but not on work laptop. But still only creates a 4616 bye cache file. Is that right?

Answer (score 11):

Calling `Activator.CreateInstance` during startup seems to kill MCJ?

Or rather that triggered an Assembly Resolve, which completely seems to stop MCJ. And never work after that. Maybe the MSDN docs should mention this.

Comment: Assembly Resolve only stops MCJ if the event is being handled by someone. If the event is fired but not being handled it won't stop MCJ.

Comment: Is there any 'official' documentation on the behaviour and limitations (such as the handled assembly resolve) of MCJ anywhere out there? So far this is the only mention of it I've found anywhere.